# ElasticBeanstalk Leaving Wide Open SSH Inbound Rules on Security Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am doing a security audit through the Amazon Inspector and it has pointed out that my elastic beanstalk ec2 instances have port 22 open to the internet. I thought this didn't sound right because I don't remember opening that up. But when I looked I found that all of the ec2s created in my beanstalk were associated with a security group, generated by the beanstalk, that had port 22 open to the internet.

[image]

Why is this?
Can I remove this?
Is there a way to have it automatically removed so I don't have to do this manually for every beanstalk application going forward?

Comment: I don't think you can stop it doing this by default, but you should be able to modify security groups with `.ebextensions`. Take a look at this answer as a starting point; https://serverfault.com/a/924375

Comment: @markwalker_ That's unfortunate. It's strange they would create a default SG with what they themselves consider a vulnerability. I'm about to do some testing but do you know if it's safe to delete that rule once it's created. I am using my own security groups from the CF template, this gets bolted on regardless.

Comment: You should be ok to remove it. After all you can still login to the console to put it back in if something stops working while you decide what you need to provide your service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove the default security group that allows traffic on port 22 by using a Lambda function. Alternatively, if you remove the SSH key from Elastic Beanstalk, it will no longer create a security group that allows traffic on port **22** for the entire 'Hello World'.

For example below is the CloudFromation stack with ElasticBeanstalk and here I need to remove this to avoid creating a default security group ssh.

```
  ElasticBeanstalkEnvironment:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
    Properties:
      EnvironmentName: !Sub '${Project}-${Environment}'
      ApplicationName: !Ref ElasticBeanstalkApplication
      SolutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.7.1 running Docker'
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
          OptionName: 'EC2KeyName'
          Value: 'my_ssh_key'
```